# Another by-election

Tags: phrase-meaning

> “If he insists on feeding the infant jaguar himself, in defiance of
>   its mother’s wishes, there may be **another by-election** in the north,”
>   said one of his colleagues, with a hopeful inflection in his voice.
>   “**By-elections** are not very desirable at present, but we must not be
>   selfish.”

[Short Stories of Saki](http://haytom.us/the-unkindest-blow/)

What is the difference between "another by-election" and "by-election"?

Comment: **another** {something} = a {something} in addition to the {something(s)} we already have or have had.   "Would you like *another* glass of juice?" implies that you have already drunk at least one glass of juice.

Answer (score 3):

It's a highly context-specific allusion to the fact that there had ***already been at least one by-election*** in the North of England recently (the story was written around 1914). This isn't *explicitly* stated earlier in the story, but it's strongly implied by the preceding paragraph which makes many references to political unrest.

Most likely the speaker represents or endorses the current ruling class, which is why he says *By-elections are not very desirable at present* (since he and/or his allies are currently in power, they'd rather keep it that way and not risk losing control "bit-by-bit" through by-elections).

And certainly the readers ***of the time*** would know all about [Britain 1911-1914: The great unrest.](http://www.socialistparty.org.uk/articles/11183)

---

Compare...

> 1: *Do you want a slap?*
>    2: *Do you want **another** slap?* (by implication, ***in addition*** to the slap/s you've already had)

Answer (score 0):

> another by-election

is talking about the possibility of a *specific* by-election, whereas

> by-election

is talking about by-elections (*any*) in general.